# extremly speciallized formatting question pages and columns with (xe)LaTeX

Tags: xetex

I have sheets of paper in A4 with two horizontal perforations. I want to print the content in such a way, that I just have to break the paper along those perforations and put the three stacks together to build a booklet.

The problem is: the text flows and it is not known in advance how many booklet-pages the result will be. All booklet-pages will be numbered and the first page(s) have the index.

f.e. I have 9 booklet-pages, so I need 3 sheets of paper, if my text gets larger so I have 10 booklet-pages I need 4 sheets of paper with 2 spare booklet-pages:

```
.-. .-. .-.
|1| |2| |3|
|4| |5| |6|
|7| |8| |9|
'-' '-' '-'

.-. .--. .-. .-.
|1| |2 | |3| |4|
|5| |6 | |7| |8|
|9| |10| | | | |
'-' '--' '-' '-'
```

**My question:** Is LaTeX capable of this?

Uptil now I do this programmatically including simple text-formatting (which I want to transfer to a system which performs better than what I am capable to program myself).

To complicate things a bit, **some** (I know which one) of the booklet-pages have a backside with reversed layout (f.e. page-number on the left instead of the right)

**update** I put some more afford into the question: I have a long text (wich is automatically generated by an external source) with chapters to be rendered by XeLaTeX (own font). the pagesize-height is 'a third A4' and printing is 'double-sided' and 'booklet-binding'. Each chapter shall start on an odd page. Only pages that have text on it shall be numbered, the first page has an address-window with empty backside, the second page(s) contain the index with numbers.

After (or while?) rendering, the pages are to be rearranged onto A4-paper as described above.

Comment: You should take a look at the `pdfpages` package. Do you mean each sheet of paper can contain `6` pages?

Comment: exactly up to 6 pages per paper. f.e. after the index-page (if it fits on one page) the backside is empty and not counted as a page (but it will be counted if the index does not fit on page 1 and will be broken over to the backside of the first paper)

Comment: the rendering of the floating text shall be done by TeX. Is your idea to generate the output into separate pdf-files per booklet-page and then rearange the pdf with `pdfpages`?